# awk - printing x amount of characters based on string length

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

So I'm trying to read some config files and output the information from find piped into grep over to awk as follows:

```
find /path/to/file/ -name config.php -print0 | xargs -0 grep -E 'cfg_database|cfg_user|cfg_password' | awk -F"[:']" -v OFS="" '{print (NR%3==1) ? $1 " | Database: " : "", (NR%3==2) ? "Username: " : "", (NR%3==0) ? "Password: " : "", $5}'
```

There would be multiple results so by default, find | xargs grep output is:

```
/path/to/file/dir1/config.php:define('cfg_database', 'db1');
/path/to/file/dir1/config.php:define('cfg_user', 'user1');
/path/to/file/dir1/config.php:define('cfg_password', 'pass1');
/path/to/file/dir2/config.php:define('cfg_database', 'db2');
/path/to/file/dir2/config.php:define('cfg_user', 'user2');
/path/to/file/dir2/config.php:define('cfg_password', 'pass2');
```

With the command I have right now, the output is:

```
/path/to/file/dir1/config.php | Database: db1
Username: user1
Password: pass1
```

But I want to be able to prepend spaces so that all of the results are lined up based on the length of path to the file ($1) plus three more spaces.

```
/path/to/file/dir1/config.php | Database: db1
                                Username: user1
                                Password: pass1
```

The only methods I'm seeing here are using a loop within print for length($1), or using printf. I couldn't figure out any ways of getting the loop in the current command, and I don't know much about printf and couldn't figure out a way of determining what line is being read. Either way, would appreciate someone pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 4):

```
your_command | awk 'FNR==1{l=index($0,"|")+1}FNR>1{$0=sprintf("%*s%s",l,"",$0)}1'
```

For example :

```
$ cat f
/path/to/file/dir1/config.php | Database: db1
Username: user1
Password: pass1

$ awk 'FNR==1{l=index($0,"|")+1}FNR>1{$0=sprintf("%*s%s",l,"",$0)}1' f
/path/to/file/dir1/config.php | Database: db1
                                Username: user1
                                Password: pass1
```

**Explanation**

- `index(str, sub)`

> It checks whether **sub** is a substring of **str** or not. On success, it
>   returns the position where **sub** starts; otherwise it returns `0`. The
>   first character of **str** is at position `1`.

- `sprintf(format, expression1, …)`

> Return (without printing) the string that `printf` would have printed
>   out with the same arguments

- `sprintf("%*s%s",l,"",$0)`

Like [C/C++](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) Specifies how much space to allocate for the string

> `*` The width is not specified in the format string, but as an
>   additional integer value argument preceding the argument that has to
>   be formatted.

```
sprintf("%*s",5,"")
```

is same as

```
sprintf("%5s", "");
```

Example

Used to specify, in a dynamic way, what the width of the field is:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{printf("%*s%s\n",5,"","mystring")}'
     mystring

$ awk 'BEGIN{printf("%5s%s\n","","mystring")}'
     mystring
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'NR==1{len=length($0)} {printf "%"len"s\n",$0}' yourfile
/path/to/file/dir1/config.php | Database: db1
                              Username: user1
                              Password: pass1
```

Here, the length of first line is used to calculate the format of the string output, its stored in `len` variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk 'NR==1{s=length($1)+4}NR>1{$s=$1 OFS $2;$1=$2=""}1' file
```

or

```
$ awk '
NR==1 {
    s=length($1)+4   # length of first field of first record + correction
}
NR>1 {
    $s=$1 OFS $2     # use length to position to correct field
    $1=$2=""         # clean original fields
}1' file
/path/to/file/dir1/config.php | Database: db1
                                Username: user1
                                Password: pass1
```